# is there a data api for the windows 7 phone marketplace?

Tags: windows-phone

Is there an api that exposes the apps in the windows 7 marketplace as odata, rest, soap or something else programmatically accessible?

Comment: Already answered. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535275/is-there-an-api-web-service-to-search-for-applications-in-the-windows-phone-mark

Comment: thanks @TalbottCrowell. probably also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535275/is-there-an-api-web-service-to-search-for-applications-in-the-windows-phone-mark

Answer (score 1):

Per the comment from @talbottcrowell, Crawling the Windows Phone Marketplace http://brandonwatson.sys-con.com/node/1767886

It's not an official api, but certainly seems to be a blessed way to do it.

there's also great docs as part of the codeplex project zunedata
http://zunedata.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=API%20Documentation